# What are the good practices/patterns with Entity Framework to return a list of entity that contains computed value

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I am wondering what is the good practices/patterns with Entity Framework to return a list of entity that contains computed value?

In details, in my DAL, I have a function that return a list of entities :

```
Return (From msg In context.Messages
         Where (msg.UserCreation.Equals(From, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).ToList()
```

This works fine and this return a List (Of Message). Message is an entity that correspond to a table in Sql Server. Now I have to modify this query so I can include a count for each "Message". I want to know the number of recipients for each message.

```
Return (From msg In context.Messages
         Let countRecipient as integer = context.MessageRecipientJeu.Count(Function(x) x.Message.UserCreation.Equals(From, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         Where (msg.UserCreation.Equals(From, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).ToList()
```

This return a anonymous type so I get an error.

What are the best solution I have?

Do I have to define a user-custom type in my entity model (in the edmx file) ? 
Should I define my own entity Message that contain a count and would be use only for this function?
Anything else?

Hopes it's clear enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the MSDN 101 LINQ samples page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb688088.aspx
It is not perfect structured (structured by operation name, not by purpose that you intend to do), but since there are so many examples, just clicking through some should give you some good examples.

e.g. here is the page for **Where** :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb737944

and here for some **IF** :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb737907

**Update**

Follow the default structure (as it is used in almost every example):

1. define a query (assign the LINQ to that variable, do not define a type or use **As System.Collections.IEnumerable** )
2. use a For-Each Loop to process each result. Here you can cast and fill the variable types that you want.

It is very common to use For Each, so I assume that it is best practices.

Also I hoped to find something that will automatically add an integer for count (I assume there is something like that in linq). It would be best solution, but wasn't able to find it right now in the examples.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I want to know the good practices to return an entity different from what's defined in my database. My entity model is generated from the database automatically.

Comment: You are right, it is no direct answer. after the update it should be 1 more idea what can help and a way that you can search for a solution until someone give a better one here. I guess this is still better than no solution at all ?

Comment: That's whats I ended with. I use a For Each and transformed my anonymous type to as one I created aside of my generated entity model. Thanks for your help